# How to change a field value of object in List at Java

Tags: java

In javascript, the value of object in array can be changed using for loop as below.

```
const list = [{company: "abc"}, {company: "def"}]
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   list[i].company = list[i].company + " okay"
}
```

it returns

[{company:"abc okay", {company:"def okay"}]

But, I try to use java for this case using ArrayList.
So I made this code.

```
result = {list:[{company:"abc"},{companay:"def"}]};

for (int i = 0; i < ((List<LectureList>) result.get("list")).size(); i++) {
    result.get("list")[i].get("company").set(i, " okay");
}

return result;
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I recommend you read through [the official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question references a few undefined things so we don't know what `result` is or what the features of `LectureList` are.  Nonetheless, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
List<LectureList> lectureLists = (List<LectureList>) result.get("list");
for (LectureList lectureList : lectureLists) {
  lectureList.setCompany(lectureList.getCompany() + " okay");
}
```

.. or ...

```
for (LectureList lectureList :  (List<LectureList>) result.get("list")) {
  lectureList.setCompany(lectureList.getCompany() + " okay");
}
```

.. or ...

```
 ((List<LectureList>) result.get("list")).forEach( lectureList -> lectureList.setCompany(lectureList.getCompany() + " okay");
```